# What's the best way to structure code once deployed to switch it on/off via a trigger?

Tags: java, android, function

I would like to be able to enable and disable various functions remotely.
By just changing a variable via tcp, websockets or traditional http.
Getting the variable to the app isn't a problem.

I would just like some direction on the best way to structure the code to flip functions on or off remotely.

I would like to flip  a variable lets say...

```
  codeAOn = true;

  public void codeA(){
     if(codeAOn){
         xyz;
     }else{ abc; }


  public void incomingVariable(Intent intent){
      if intent.equals("codeAoff"){
          codeAOn = false;
  }
```

I can see where this code above can turn messy real quick, any suggestions available?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component, let's call it FlagProvider, with the following interface:

```
boolean getFlag(String flagName, boolean defaultValue)
```

The flags can be set in whatever way you want.

To check the flag:

```
if (flagProvider.getFlag("codeAOn", false)) { ... }
```

If this is still too messy because flag values come from multiple sources, then you might want to create a class for each source: one for hard-coded flags, one for flags coming from your server etc, and unify them under the provider. The provider will get the value of the flag from one of the sources according to the priority between the sources that you decide upon.

What you're proposing is called "feature flags" or just "configuration".

Comment: can you give an example in the same style on setting the flag

Comment: You can set the flag in multiple ways. For example, it can be in a configuration file.